# Speculative hand with a lot of draws

Tags: odds, poker-strategy

Say you are playing 7♥ 8♥ in position and call a min raise pre.

Flop comes up Q♥ 7⋄ 6♣

On the flop villain bets 1/2 the pot.  How do you play it out?

Both deep stacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think implied odds are the main focus of this hand, at least some of the time the pre-flop raiser is c-betting with absolutely nothing so there is immediate odds. Calling the half pot bet on the flop is something I would do most of the time depending on the player. Even if the pre-flop raiser has a hand like top pair or a pocket pair, there is a pretty good chance my hand will improve, so calling the flop would pay off in the long run. I would avoid calling something like this if there is a lot of action on the flop and the flop is multi-way, if that is the case then the chances of having the best hand are very slim.

Comment: What makes you believe you are not getting immediate odds to call here?

Comment: I would be, but if not there is good implied odds as well. Could be clearer i will edit

Answer (score 0):

I will not accept my own answer.  I was curios about running the numbers.

---

**Pre**

I am good with calling with a speculative hand like this.  Would actually like more players in the pot.

---

**Flop**
Bottom pair is better than nothing but not great.  Back door straight and flush draws.  Villain could be on any ace, two overs, and 22-TT.  JJ+ probably would have raised more pre.  Even if you put 7 in his range the worse case scenario 99-22, A2s+, K7s+,Q7s+, J7s+, T9s, A2o+,K7o+, Q7o+, J7o+ you are 65:35.  I was surprised it was that high.  It kind of makes this a less interesting question.  Over 1/2 the time you are ahead here and with so many ways to improve almost don't mind if villain has pair of queens to get paid off.  5 immediate outs.  And 23 outs to fill in the back door draws.  Pretty clear call.  I don't see raise here.

---

**Turn**
Even if I don't improve on the turn I would call up to 1/2 pot.

If like the 9 hearts came up to give both draws I think I would raise back a pot to either take it down or build a pot.

---

**River**
If I miss and they bet 1/2 pot again on the river I think I need to let it go.  If I hit 2 pr I think I just call.  Trips or better then raise like the pot again.